# Peanut oil with maybe some residue of raw egg

Tags: food-safety, oil

I  poured too much oil into the measuring cup, so I poured some back into the bottle.   However, the measuring cup was used for eggs before measuring the oil. I rinsed it from  the eggs but didn't wash it properly with soap, just water. Did I contaminate the whole bottle of oil, or is it safe to use? I put the bottle of oil in the fridge after that and the color and texture changed

Comment: oil in the fridge will solidify; as for the eggs, I don't know.

Comment: More specifics about "color and texture changed" would be helpful here

Comment: Oil with an unexpected pocket of watery liquid in it could become unsafe in another, more treacherous way - a drop of water in oil that is being heated from cold tends to very, very abruptly leave once its boiling point is reached....

Answer (score 4):

If you heat the oil to around 95C, any egg residue should solidify and the oil should be sterilised at the temperature. You can then strain the oil and decant off any aqueous phase. If you want a more certain clearing, make a small amount of brine say 5% salt by weight, pour it into the oil, shake it up, let it settle and separate out, decant the oil phase and heat it to 95C and strain.

addendum: there is a somewhat related method [here](http://www.seriouseats.com/2016/06/clean-cooking-oil-with-gelatin-technique.html)

Comment: Only if you can rely on all the water separating and/or your heating never going above a 100°C ;)

Comment: Very much so @rackandboneman. My experience is that there is always tiny droplets of water suspended in the oil. So, the first time you heat the oil after a water wash, you always get some spattering.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry to say but I would tend to lean towards cross contamination...

Raw egg being the poultry produce it is, is certainly a vector for potential salmonella contamination and, well, I would simply not risk cooking with it, especially since oil tends to last much longer than a few days for me.

I know good quality oils can be quite expensive, but I would toss it, simply because a bottle of peanut oil is not worth potential salmonella in my opinion.

Comment: The color and consistency change is probably due to refrigeration, but, yeah, rinsing the measuring cup was probably not enough for mixing it back in.

Comment: @user110084's answer is legitimate, but I simply wouldn't risk it. If I can avoid cross-contamination I will. Perhaps this oil could be used as frying oil though instead of being wasted, and like he said, heat it up before preserving it for future use in order to kill off bacteria

Comment: To be honest @Louis, if it happened to me and it is peanut oil and not litres and litres of it, I would not want the risk or the hassle.

Comment: Indeed. If it's a small amount... I think I would just toss.